# CASE WHEN with INTERVAL mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare two data in a table. If a date in one field - 3 days < from a day in another filed then 1, else 0.

Here is I have been trying: SELECT

```
SELECT
    COUNT(SUM(IF(DATE(gl.logintime) < DATE_ADD(DATE(ds.register_time), INTERVAL 3 DAY), 1, 0))) as `three`, 
    COUNT(SUM(IF(DATE(gl.logintime) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(ds.register_time), INTERVAL 3 DAY)), 1, 0)) as `seven`
    FROM direct_search ds
      LEFT JOIN good_liar gl
        ON gl.data_id = ds.dataid
      INNER JOIN coolme cm 
        ON cm.coolmed = ds.coolme_id
      INNER JOIN goodme gm 
        ON gm.goodid = cm.good_id                                               
    WHERE DATE(ds.register_time) = '2015-05-01'
      AND gm.goodme_name LIKE 'Thhunder'
    GROUP BY ds.register_time
```

It gives me error.

But when I delete the `COUNT` query and leave the `SUM` itself, it doesn't sum the result instead only giving me the result of 1 and 0 of each rows. (I want to count how many row does the result for 1 and 0.

How to correctly do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error.

Comment: which one? can you tell me, please?

Comment: I think, you have to use sub selects.

Comment: can you show me the example, @Joerg? Thanks

Comment: SOLVE, the problem is I don't need to group it anymore. lol

Comment: `COUNT(SUM(IF(DATE(gl.logintime) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(ds.register_time), INTERVAL 3 DAY)), 1, 0))` for one of these you close parentheses three times at the end, the other only twice. Not a syntax error, but different nesting of functions so inconsistent results